# Static variable cannot be resolved

Tags: c++, hyperlink, static

In my VC++ 2008 project, I create two files, Globals.h and Globals.cpp, as follows:

Glboals.h:

```
#pragma once

extern ULONG g_ulMAPIUnicodeFlag;
```

Globals.cpp:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Globals.h"
#include <mapidefs.h>

#ifdef _UNICODE

static ULONG g_ulMAPIUnicodeFlag = MAPI_UNICODE;

#else

static ULONG g_ulMAPIUnicodeFlag = 0;

#endif
```

Then I use the global variable in another file, TestGlboalDlg.cpp, as follows:

```
#include "Globals.h"

...

void CTestGlobalDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    ULONG a;

    a = g_ulMAPIUnicodeFlag;
}
```

But get the following link error:

```
TestGlobalDlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "unsigned long g_ulMAPIUnicodeFlag" (?g_ulMAPIUnicodeFlag@@3KA)
```

Why? If I remove the static modifier in GLobals.cpp, then everything is OK. However, static modifier is required since I need to set the value of the flag at the beginning of the program.

Thanks

Comment: `static`'s purpose on a declaration at namespace scope is exactly to *not* make the declaration visible to other translation units. It does not mean the same as `static` on a declaration inside a class or at block scope. `static` is not required to initialize the variable at program startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

static is the exact opposite of extern. Do not mix the two.

```cpp
#ifdef _UNICODE

ULONG g_ulMAPIUnicodeFlag = MAPI_UNICODE;

#else

ULONG g_ulMAPIUnicodeFlag = 0;

#endif
```